# How can I tell where Named Ranges are acutally used?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, named-ranges

I inherited a rather complex Excel workbook with multiple sheets and TONS of named ranges. Don't get me wrong I LOVE named ranges in Excel, but.... I suspect the the creator of this monster went nuts with them. I also suspect that many of these named ranges never got used anywhere in any of the formulas, or got abandoned at some point during development.

How can I tell which named ranges are actually referenced and in use within the workbook?

Comment: Did you see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26687463/find-where-named-ranges-are-being-used-in-big-workbook)?  Also, if you have a list of your named ranges, you can use `Find`, and just search in Formulas.

Comment: There's also [this page](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3138-excel-find-where-named-range-is-used.html). What have you tried so far?  There's going to be many ways to do this, VBA is likely the solution - but please let us know what's worked, what hasn't for you.